# Is there a way to make sure that my bytes are loading properly when I use the sb command in MIPS?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am coding in MIPS and trying to replace every matching character in a string with another character supplied by the user. My problem is the actual replacement. I'm trying to use sb to move the replacement character into the correct spot, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
while:
        lb $t2, 0($t5)      #Loads the next byte of the string into 
                                 temporary storage

        beqz $t2, exit      #If the next byte is empty, we're done

        beq $t2, $t1, replacer  #If the next character matches, replace the 
                                 character
        replacerContinue:

        addi $t0, $t0, 1    #Increments the address for the modded array
        addi $t5, $t5, 1    #Increments original string
        j while

.
.
.
.


replacer:
        sb $t4, 0($t0)  <----   #Stores the replacement character at the bit 
                                 in the current offset for the modified string
        j replacerContinue
        syscall
```

Here's a bit of a key for the registers, I know it's a bit of a mess:

$t0 = The modified version of the original string that should contain the new 
      character in replacement of the old character

$t1 = The character that the user wants to replace in the string

$t2 = The byte in the string for $t5

$t4 = The character that the user has chosen to replace the old character with

$t5 = The original string. It was input earlier by the user, and I have it 
      stored in the.data component

I was expecting that when I used sb $t4, 0($t0), it would store the replacement character into the corresponding spot of the old character (notice that I increment the addresses at the end of the loop, so I shouldn't need to add an offset).

Instead, I can't tell whether anything is happening. I'm using MARS, and when I look at the register value to see if the replacement is happening at $t0, it only shows the value of the address.

Thanks for your help. Let me know if I can provide any more information, or if you notice any bad practices in my code writing. I'm still very new to MIPS.

Comment: You need to look in the Data Segment viewer, at the address that `$t0` currently contains. You can even configure it to show the data as ASCII characters.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try.